# Why do I need to return the pointer of a function

Tags: c, pointers

I haven't programmed with pointers for a long time and I do not remember when I need to return a `char *` or not! Let me make a example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 

void AllocMemory(char** buf);

int main(){
    
   char *array;

   AllocMemory(&array);

   printf("%s", array); //Printing and I dont make return
   
   free(array);

   return 0; 
}
    
void AllocMemory(char** buf){
    
    int bufSize = 10;
    int stringSize;
        
    *buf = calloc(bufSize, sizeof(char)); 
        
    if(*buf == NULL){
        printf("[ERROR] can't malloc %d bytes\n", bufSize);
        exit(1);
    }
    char *readpos = *buf; //point to a pointer of your array!
        
    while(1){   //looping until the alocated memory is enough to the inserted command

        do{

            fgets(readpos, bufSize, stdin); //reads a line from the specified stream

            stringSize = strlen(*buf); //getting the size of the array

            if (stringSize == 1)
            {
                printf("\nYou just pressed enter, pls type again: "); //checking if user just pressed enter
            }

        }while (stringSize == 1); //looping until user press only enter

    
        if (readpos[strlen(readpos)-1] == '\n'){ //Search from the end as there's where the newline should be if exists, the string fits on array and doesnt need to allocate more memory
                readpos[strlen(readpos)-1] = '\0';     //Remove \n from the string
                break;
        }   

        
        *buf = realloc(*buf, bufSize + stringSize * sizeof(char)); // Need to allocate more memory, because the before if its false
        if(*buf == NULL){
            printf("[ERROR] can't realloc more %d bytes\n", bufSize+stringSize);
            exit(1);
        } 

        readpos = *buf + stringSize; // Set the pointer to next position to read into 
    }
        
}
```

So in this case I think I don't need to return a `char*`, but sometimes I need to return it, I and I am wondering if its when its when the parameter is send as example:

```
char *examplefunc(char *buf){
   //Code here
}
```

So my question can be bad, but what I need to know, is when I need to return the `char *` or not!

```
void redirection(char** stringSplited, char** cRedirection, char** fRedirection){ 

   //I has splited the `stringSplited` here and save some parameters do `cRedirection and to fRedirection`and I do not need any return;
}
```

Comment: You should return char *, if you are not taking reference as input as in big code. If you don't take reference, you are just duplicating item, the actual item doesn't get passed.

Comment: @Fawad So If i do not return in big code what could happens, because its working without return anything!

Comment: In your case of examplefunc(char *buf), char *buf will also point to what char *array is pointing, but that's it. buf cannot change what the array will point to. But if you send the address of array(as in big code), you can de-reference it and change what char *array will point to (as you are doing in *buf = realloc(*buf, bufSize + stringSize * sizeof(char)); // Need to allocate more memory, because the before if its false)

Comment: @Fawad But if I declare it as char** then I can edit the value of array, so If I dont want do declare the type char** I can simply edit the values on my function and the returns it, and if I equalize my var array to the function, the is value will be changed!

Comment: Yes, you got it right, as I read your other comment you are sending more than one character array, so it's better to send them as reference, because you can only return one item!

Comment: @Fawad Exactly! And I cannot make more than one return! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are just a reference (address) pointing to some memory. If you pass `char*` to a function, then the function will be able to use it to change the content stored at this address ; and naturally, the address you pass hasn't changed, so you may use the pointer you provided even outside of that function.

You want to pass a `char**` when you want to modify a pointer itself and not the content it points to. In your example, you provide a `char**` to your `AllocMemory()` function, and it allocates memory at the address (which would be of type `char*`)  pointed to by your double pointer `buf`. Returning anything is unnecessary, as you've modified the memory adequately, and so `array` in your `main()` will point to an address that has been initiated in your function. This address will point to the memory you initiated and manipulated in your function.

You're confused over whether or not to return values because you don't seem to fully grasp how pointers work - understandably so, it's an unintuitive idea. But if you understand what you are accessing and the difference between a pointer `char*` and a pointer to a pointer `char**`, then you'll know when you want to return a pointer and when it's unnecessary. It depends on the context, and it's unnecessary in this case.

Comment: So in this case I dont need to return anything! I just need to return when I change is content?

Comment: Yes but in my head, I do not need to return it, if I declare it always type of char**, because it will be a pointer that points to another pointer, so if I change the value of variable, It will be changed outside the function

Comment: @GonçaloBastos Indeed, you don't need to return anything in this case - I edited my answer to clarify that point. And for your second comment, if you use pointers in this way, then yes, returning will not be necessary

Comment: Oh okey, so thats explain a lot to me! Because I made a school project in another day, and I do not return anything but I split the strings and save them to another char** variables, and then I can acess to them on my main! So if I declare a char** like I did on the example I do not need to return anything?

Comment: @GonçaloBastos If I understand you correctly, you want to initialize a `char**` inside another function. If that's the case, then it works the same way, but the function will take a `char***` as parameter instead : a pointer to a `char**`.

Comment: no I was saying that I has made something like on my big code, but 
beyond of buf I have more 2 variables of type char** and I do not return anything, but I can acess to their values on my main!

Comment: So I splitted a string that was like `"ls -la > file.txt"` and save `"ls -la"` to `cRedirection` and `"file.txt"` to `fReditection` and I do not need to return anything!

Answer (score 2):

It's always possible to change return value to output parameters. For instance, here are two functions that both add two numbers.

```
int add1(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

void add2(int a, int b, int *output) {
    *output = a+b;
}
```

And then you invoke them just a little bit differently. But they work the same way.

```
int x, y;
x = add1(5, 6);
add2(5, 6, &y);
```

This is not different just because it's a pointer. A pointer is just a variable containing a memory address. The function `realloc` has this signature:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
```

But that's just a design choice. This would work just as good:

```
void realloc(void *ptr, size_t size, void **output)
```

Or to put it in more general terms, this function:

```
T foo(<params>) {
    ...
    return <expr>;
}
```

can be converted to this:

```
void foo(<params>, T *output) {
    ...
    *output = <expr>;
}
```

The easiest way is to just write it as a wrapper:

```
void new_foo(<params>, T *output) {
    *output = old_foo(<params>);
}
```

Or vice versa:

```
T *new_foo(<params>) {
    T *ret;
    old_foo(<params>, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

> My confusion was why I need to return a char* if I can declare it in function like this `void examplefucn(char ** buf);`

You don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for you asnwer, my problem is not with int, I am confused about strings, when I declare a variable type of char* and declare it on the function as char** why I need to return it back!

Comment: @GonçaloBastos It's no difference. A pointer is a variable just like an int.

Comment: I understand now! Thanks for your time!

Comment: My confusion was why I need to return a `char*` if I can declare it in function like this `void examplefunc(char ** buf);`